# VBA code for index/match function not working properly

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I wrote the following macro to create a dynamic index/match formula which retrieves data from one sheet (US acq_CUSIP data) and outputs it to another (ws_output). My code is below, ws_input contains a bunch of data incl. a list of companies (in the range R43:R3223) and calendar years (for example, 2011, 2012, etc.). When trying to run the macro, I get the following error: "Application-defined or object-defined error", which seems to be due to the errors in the resulting index formula. How can I fix this? Thank you!

```
Sub fetching_acq_data_compustat()

Dim ws_input As Worksheet
Dim strTkr As String
Dim rngTkr As Range
Dim c As Range

Dim ws_output As Worksheet
Dim strTaxPaid As String
Dim StrPretaxIncome As String
Dim strSpecItem As String
Dim strTkrCell As String
Dim Dated As String
Dim strDatedCell As String


Set ws_input = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MA_ExportFiltered_RawData")
Set ws_output = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Acquirer_ETR")


ws_output.Activate

With ws_output
    Set rngTkr = .Range("R43:R3223")
    i = 1
    For Each c In rngTkr
    
        strTkrCell = c.Address
        
        k = 14
        If k < 16 Then
        Dated = c.Offset(0, k).Address
        strDatedCell = Dated
        
        ws_output.Range("A1").Offset(2, 0).Value = c.Offset(0, 14).Value
        
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Value = "=INDEX( 'US acq_CUSIP data'!$A$3:$AJ$77388" & ";" & "MATCH(1; ('US acq_CUSIP data'!$I$3:$I$77388=" & "MA_ExportFiltered_RawData!" & strTkrCell & ")*('US acq_CUSIP data'!$C$3:$C$77388=" & "MA_ExportFiltered_RawData!" & strDatedCell & ");0); 26)"
        
        ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value = 26
        
        ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value = c.Value
        
        k = k + 1
        
        End If
        
    Next
End With
    

End Sub
```

Comment: Avoid using `ActiveCell` wherever possible, as it's very prone to causing bugs - if the selection changes during the code for any reason it can cause problems. Much better to `Dim` a range variable and set it as the active cell at the start of the code, then make all your `.Offset()` statements relative to that, at least that variable can't change by accident.

Comment: If you `Debug.print` the formula it's trying to insert, then manually type that into the sheet, does it throw errors?

Comment: @SpencerBarnes this is what the debug.print prints out: `=INDEX( 'US acq_CUSIP data'!$A$3:$AJ$77388;MATCH(1; ('US acq_CUSIP data'!$I$3:$I$77388=MA_ExportFiltered_RawData!"$R$1264")*('US acq_CUSIP data'!$C$3:$C$77388=MA_ExportFiltered_RawData!"$AF$1264");0); 26)`. Edit: I also changed the range to R43:R48 to test this out, otherwise the macro takes too long

Comment: @SpencerBarnes I tried changing `ActiveCell` to `ws_output.Range()` (the way it's done in the first statement, adjusting the offsetting of rows/columns correspondingly, but this does not seem to solve the issue

Comment: @SpencerBarnes also now I closed the document, opened it again and the immediate window just remains empty when I run the macro??

Comment: ... and if you copy/paste the `debug.print` output above into a cell in the sheet, does it work? If it's a problem with the formula, the error thrown by the sheet (formula editor) will be more helpful than that thrown by the VBA. Just copy from your comment above rather than trying to get it back out of the code,

Comment: @SpencerBarnes the formula I pasted here indeed retrieves the right value (for the company/year combination specified by R1264 and AF1264), however, this requires deleting the double quotes around both cell addresses first (as this is the standard excel syntax for index/match). So, the major issue seem to be those double quotes which I somehow need to get rid of.

Comment: @SpencerBarnes do you maybe have any suggestion on how I can best remove the "" around the cell addresses?

Comment: Looking at where those are in the vba, that means that the double quotes are being added into the two string variables `strDatedCell` and `strTkrCell`

Comment: Would you just check the above? `Debug.print` those variables and see if they have quotes in. I can't see where in the code they'd have been introduced - I take it this isn't the entire sub, you've trimmed out irrelevant parts?

Comment: @SpencerBarnes surprisingly, now neither of them has double quotes. Also, I copied my entire code, so maybe there is an issue with introducing/declaring variables, which I'm missing? Plus, the list I am using for the R:R range is filtered, can this cause the issue?

Comment: @SpencerBarnes the formula iself now looks like this: `=INDEX( 'US acq_CUSIP data'!$A$3:$AJ$77388;MATCH(1; ('US acq_CUSIP data'!$I$3:$I$77388=MA_ExportFiltered_RawData!$R$143)*('US acq_CUSIP data'!$C$3:$C$77388=MA_ExportFiltered_RawData!$AF$143);0); 26)`, which gives me proper results when copied directly into excel. Still, VBA complaines about the same error and the right part being "empty"

Comment: Shouldn't you use `.Formula2` instead of `.Value`?

Comment: @P.b. replacing .Value with .Formula2 does not solve the issue, the "helper comment" (not sure how it should be called, but this is what appears when you hover over the line of code) now is: `ws_output.Range("A1").Offset(2, 1).Formula2 = ""  `

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer to the question, but it's too long to post in comments (plus the comment discussion was getting too long anyway).

If as you say the above is your entire code without anything trimmed out for relevance, then I've refactored it to the below (which does exactly the same actions just with less code):

```
Sub fetching_acq_data_compustat()
'Variables:
    'Worksheets:
Dim ws_input As Worksheet, ws_output As Worksheet
Set ws_input = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MA_ExportFiltered_RawData")
Set ws_output = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Acquirer_ETR")
    'Ranges:
Dim rngTkr As Range, c As Range
    'Strings:
Dim strTkrCell As String, strDatedCell As String

With ws_output
    .Activate
    Set rngTkr = .Range("R43:R3223")
    For Each c In rngTkr ' This loop achieves nothing because the same cells are getting edited every time, the end result will be just the results of the last iteration of the loop
        strTkrCell = c.Address
        strDatedCell = c.Offset(0, 14).Address
        
    ' there were variables i and k in here which weren't doing anything; 
    ' i got set but then never incremented
    ' k got set and incremented, but then reset to its original value for every loop of c

        .Range("A1").Offset(2, 0).Value = c.Offset(0, 14).Value
' substituted 'Range("A1")' for 'Activecell'; that may be wrong.
        .Range("A1").Offset(0, 1).Value = _
            "=INDEX('US acq_CUSIP data'!$A$3:$AJ$77388;MATCH(1;('US acq_CUSIP data'!$I$3:$I$77388=MA_ExportFiltered_RawData!" & strTkrCell & ")*('US acq_CUSIP data'!$C$3:$C$77388=MA_ExportFiltered_RawData!" & strDatedCell & ");0); 26)"
        .Range("A1").Offset(-1, 0).Value = c.Value
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

As mentioned in the comments (and further noticeable from the code) there were variables that weren't getting used, and the loop through `c` isn't achieving anything either.

I recommend you use F8 to step through your code line-by-line and work out if it's doing what you expected it would.

Comment: thanks a lot, I'll use your suggestions to clean up my code. Yet, I have the following question. The formula created using this macro appears to be correct (as shown via `Debug.Print` and copying it into Excel), yet, the message I get when hovering over this line of code is `.Range.Offset().Value = Empty`. I found that "Empty" in this context means that the variable has not been initialized, but I don't know how exactly I can fix this, as this line of code is not creating any new variable. Thank you!